# filenotfoundexception and file exists

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

is not the first time that I use files in java, but it is the first time that I use `FileInputStream`.

I have a TXT in resources/backup.txt

[image]

Then in my code, when I put the file in the `FileInputStream` constructor it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

This is the code:

```
public void loadList()  {

    try {

        ArrayList<Partido> myList = Pronosticos.getInstance().getMyList();
        myList.clear();


        File file = new File("resources/backup.txt");
        // create an ObjectInputStream for the file
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        // read and print an object and cast it as ArrayList<Partido>
        if (file.length() != 0){
            myList .addAll((ArrayList<Partido>) ois.readObject());
            ois.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I should not put the Path from my PC because I need it to work in another PC.

Comment: Try with just `backup.txt` as filename instead of `resources/backup.txt`

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  I tested this with the same project setup:

```
//note the beginning forward slash
URL url = getClass().getResource("/backup.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Comment: C:\Users\Casa\Downloads\eclipse Yes thats is the working directory. The problem is that I need the program to works fine in another computer, so If I put that path it will only work in my PC.

Comment: Updated my answer. It is similar to the other answers, but with the added forward slash that you need

Answer (score 0):

Try loading file like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("backup.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

And pass file object to `FileInputStream`

Comment: I got NullPointerException.